# Use of typename for vector iterator - C++11 example

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

This is reproduced from [Stroustroup's FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html).  I've seen typename used when you don't know the type, for instance in templates, `template <typename> class some_class`.  Why is typename used in the example below?

```
    template<class T> void printall(const vector<T>& v)
    {
        for (auto p = v.begin(); p!=v.end(); ++p)
            cout << *p << "\n";
    }

In C++98, we'd have to write 

    template<class T> void printall(const vector<T>& v)
    {
        for (typename vector<T>::const_iterator p = v.begin(); p!=v.end(); ++p)
            cout << *p << "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is exactly the typical example. Since `vector<T>` is used with a templated parameter `T` we have to tell the compiler that `::const_iterator` is a type. This is there to help the compiler to know that for any T the `vector<T>` type has a *type* named const_iterator.

Comment: So the iterator depends upon not only the container type but what it holds..that is an iterator for vector<int> is different than an iterator for vector<float>?

Comment: vector<float> is completely specified so the compiler can just use it like any other type at that point.

Comment: @GuyMontag - compiler cannot know that `vector<T>::const_iterator` is a type at all. It could be a method or a static data member, and the compiler won't know until it creates a concrete type from the `vector` template.